# Shortcut for switching to workspace 2 not working

Tags: keyboard, dock, desktop, spaces, mission-control

I have four desktops named "Desktop 1-4". My keyboard shortcuts for "Switch to Desktop 1,2,3,4" are CMD+a,s,d,f respectively. Sometimes CMD+s will stop working, and no longer switch to "Desktop 2". All the other desktops still work. I can still switch to "Desktop 2" using the CMD+left/right shortcuts. I've tried changing back to the default ^+1,2,3,4 shortcuts, and ^2 still doesn't work. The desktops show normally and in-order in Mission Control. If I run `killall Dock` (sometimes several times), eventually I will be able to switch to Workspace 2, but it will eventually stop working again.

Is there a better way to fix this than running `killall Dock` regularly?

Comment: I wouldn't ever use Cmd/a or s. Cmd + any single letter is often going to conflict, but Cmd/a is universal for Select All & Cmd/s is Save. There should be no conflict with Ctrl + num, however, if you have an extended keyboard with a 10-key numpad, note that the Mac considers the numbers above qwerty & those in the numpad to be *distinct keys* for command recognition.

Comment: CMD+a and CMD+s are more comfortable from an ergonomic standpoint, and are also how I've had my linux machines configured for years, so it's an ingrained habit. Either way, the problem persists with the default ^1-4 keybinds, which I'm operating from the number row, not the numpad.

Comment: The problem with reassigning keybindings like this is applications are expecting certain things.  By reassigning them, you will have unintended results, which appear to be what you’re experiencing

Comment: Based on @Tetsujin's comment, CMD+s and CMD+a are typically "save" and "select all". Are you saying that an application interpreting one of those would explain workspace 2 becoming inaccessible (even via the normal ^2 shortcut) until Dock is restarted?

Comment: You've got something interfering with it, far more likely using CMD + char but easy to do accidentally with Ctrl + char.. Unfortunately, the only way to figure out if you've set up a conflict yourself is to go right down the shortcuts list manually. It would be unusual for any  regular app to use ctrl/something, though not impossible. Terminal-type apps do it a lot. One test for a conflict would be to set something 'impossible' for Space 2, like Cmd/Ctrl/Opt/Shift/F12 [or higher if you have an extended keyboard] That way, chances of conflict are vastly reduced.

Comment: I tried binding cmd+ctrl+opt+f12 to "Switch to Desktop 2" and it still doesn't work.